# Jquery sortable while dragging on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using Jquery's sortable plugin, my question is as follows:

When i'm dragging an element, once I hover a specified element with the one I am dragging, I want a function to be initiated. Remember, not when i hover the element with my mouse, but with the element I am dragging.

Thanks a lot for any help I get with this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event after a [`sortstart`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-start) is fired

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
   start: function() { 
      $('#elementThatWillBeHoveredOver').hover(hoverStart, hoverEnd);
   }
   stop: function() { $('#elementThatWillBeHoveredOver').off('hover') }
});
```

Comment: nope sorry. two reasons why this doesn't work:
1. I'm draggin an element, so it's anyhow going to be above the element we're trying to hover.
2. I want a function to start when the draggable element hovers the other element and not when the mouse hovers it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you.
I tried several alternatives one with the method "Droppable", there is a jQuery plugin Droppable.

https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/

```
$( ".Permissoes > div" ).droppable({
    over: function(event, ui){
        console.log('fn:over',event,ui);
    },
    out: function(event, ui){
        console.log('fn:out',event,ui);
    },
    drop: function(event, ui){
        console.log('fn:drop',event,ui);
    }
);
```